# Linear operators on closed sets

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

In Brezis' Functional Analysis, exercise 6.2, item 1 is the following

> Let $E$ and $F$ two Banach spaces, and $T: E \rightarrow F$ a continuous linear operator.
>
> Assume $E$ is reflexive. Prove that $T(B_E)$ is closed (strongly).

In pg 62 ones read

> suppose that T is continuous from $E$ weak into $F$ weak. Then $G(T)$ is closed in $E \times F$ equipped with the product topology $\sigma(E, E^*) \times \sigma(F, F^*)$ (...). It fallows that $G(T)$ is strongly closed.

Theorem 3.10 gives the above continuity for $T$ in weak topology and with Kakutani's Theorem ensures that $B_E$ is compact in the weak topology. The above comment is enough to finish the proof for the question?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've stated definitely helps.  As you've noted, $T$ is weak-to-weak continuous, and since $E$ is reflexive, $B_E$ is weakly compact.  Thus $T(B_E)$ is weakly compact, hence weakly closed, and therefore norm closed.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm a little confused for the operators here. Can I assert that  if T is linear continuous and A is (weak) closed then T(A) is closed (weak) strong?

Comment: You don't need convexity in the last step.  A weakly closed set is always norm closed.  You need convexity for the converse.

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes but my question is whether can I say that T(A) is closed or not

Comment: @NateEldredge Duh I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @gdlm In general the assertion made in your comment is not true; $T$ need not map closed sets to closed sets, regardless of the topologies used.

Comment: @Aweygan , yeah, I wasn't sure if the result of continuous maps over compacts sets holds for infinite dimensions too, thanks again.

Comment: @NateEldredge, know that feeling hahaha :)

Comment: @gdlm You're welcome, glad to help!